# Is there a way for me to avoid the for loop or make it more efficient?

Tags: r, loops

I want to pick one element from x, one element from y (x and y are mutually exclusive), and one element from x or y that has not already been selected. I then want to repeat the process a specified number of times and store the results of each trial in a dataframe. (note: I am not interested in trying to find every possible combination)

The code below works but slows considerably as the number of trials increases.

```
x <- 1:4
y <- 5:8
z <- c(x, y) #edited - previous code read a, b in place of x, y
trials <- 5
sel <- data.frame()
set.seed(123)
for (i in 1:trials){
    x_sel <- sample(x, 1)
    y_sel <- sample(y, 1)
    rem <- z[!(z %in% c(x_sel, y_sel))]
    z_sel <- sample(rem, 1)
    sel <- rbind(sel, cbind(x_sel, y_sel, z_sel))
}
```

Comment: In line 3 did you mean to write `z <- c(x, y)`?

Comment: Yes, my post has been edited to reflect the change. I initially used a, b, and c as vectors but switched to x, y, and z to avoid confusion with the `c()` function. Unfortunately, I missed lines 3 and 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should probably be somewhat faster, but I doubt it's the fastest possible. Certainly Rcpp would be the fastest, I would think.

```
> set.seed(123)
> x <- 1:4
> y <- 5:8
> z <- c(x, y)
> trials <- 5
> 
> xval <- sample(x,size = trials,replace = TRUE)
> yval <- sample(y,size = trials,replace = TRUE)
> zval <- mapply(FUN = function(x,y,z) {sample(setdiff(z,c(x,y)),1)},
                             x = xval,
                             y = yval,
                             MoreArgs = list(z = z))
> 
> result <- data.frame(xval = xval,
                                         yval = yval,
                                         zval = zval)
> result
  xval yval zval
1    2    5    8
2    4    7    3
3    2    8    6
4    4    7    5
5    4    6    1
```

At only 10k samples, this appears to be ~37x faster than your for loop (which was primarily inefficient because of the appending things one at a time onto `sel`, not anything inherent in the `for` loop). The difference between this and a more sensibly written `for` loop would likely be much less.

Answer (score 1):

My approach is not elegant but seems to be efficient when a number of trials is large. In order to prove it I created 3 function: f1 - yours, f2 - joran's, f3 - mine

```
library(microbenchmark)

f1 <- function() {
   x <- 1:4
   y <- 5:8
   z <- c(x, y) #edited - previous code read a, b in place of x, y
   trials <- 5000
   sel <- data.frame()
   set.seed(123)
   for (i in 1:trials) {
      x_sel <- sample(x, 1)
      y_sel <- sample(y, 1)
      rem <- z[!(z %in% c(x_sel, y_sel))]
      z_sel <- sample(rem, 1)
      sel <- rbind(sel, cbind(x_sel, y_sel, z_sel))
   }
   return(sel)
}

f2 <- function() {
   set.seed(123)
   x <- 1:4
   y <- 5:8
   z <- c(x, y)
   trials <- 5000

   xval <- sample(x, size = trials, replace = TRUE)
   yval <- sample(y, size = trials, replace = TRUE)
   zval <-
      mapply(
         FUN = function(x, y, z) {
            sample(setdiff(z, c(x, y)), 1)
         },
         x = xval,
         y = yval,
         MoreArgs = list(z = z)
      )

   result <- data.frame(xval = xval,
                        yval = yval,
                        zval = zval)
   return(result)
}


f3 <- function() {
   x <- 1:4
   y <- 5:8
   z <- c(x, y) #edited - previous code read a, b in place of x, y
   trials <- 5000
   set.seed(123)
   x_sel <- sample(x, trials, replace = TRUE)
   y_sel <- sample(y, trials, replace = TRUE)
   z_mac <- matrix(z,
                   nrow = trials,
                   ncol = length(z),
                   byrow = TRUE)
   take <- z_mac != x_sel & z_mac != y_sel
   z_sel <- t(matrix(t(z_mac)[t(take)], ncol = trials))
   take <- sample(1:ncol(z_sel), size = trials, replace = TRUE)
   cbind(x_sel, y_sel, z_sel = z_sel[cbind(1:trials, take)])
}


microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3(), times = 10L)

Unit:milliseconds
expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq         max neval
f1() 2193.448113 2248.442450 2258.626023 2258.135072 2267.333956 2346.457082    10
f2()  205.124501  208.672947  213.520267  212.208095  219.397101  222.990083    10
f3()    2.463567    2.491762    2.570517    2.512588    2.603582    2.827863    10
```

My f3 function is 856 times faster than f1 and 83 times faster than f2. When we consider oryginal problem (trials=5) then

```
> microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3(), times = 10L)
Unit: microseconds
 expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
 f1() 1215.924 1268.790 1296.7610 1300.5095 1321.015 1370.998    10
 f2()  587.937  590.500  619.6248  612.9285  638.881  687.261    10
 f3()   68.886   78.819   86.7652   81.2225   91.315  116.947    10
```

Comment: When I implemented your code on my actual data where x has 65 elements and y has 57 elements (there are additional vectors as well) it ran slightly longer than Joran's solution. It is still much more efficient than my original code.

Comment: I don't know how it's possible. I rerun the code where `length(x)=length(y)=100` and `trials=5` and `trails =5000`. `f3` is still faster. (I corrected the above code of `f3`: should by `x_sel` but not `x_sel2` in a line when you first see a variable take). Obviously my function is not flexible and is adjusted to only 2 variables (`x` and `y`). Of course it can be extended for more variables with ease but I don't how efficiency will heart.